# How to install latest Angular CLI using visual studio 2017 Node.js interactive Window?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, angular

I am trying to install Angular CLI using Visual Studio 2017 but it throws an exception while running the command.

```
  > .npm [On.Store.UI] install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
Cached binary found at C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3\win32-x64-48_binding.node
> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
Binary found at C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-pre-gyp@0.6.33 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\node-pre-gyp' -> 'C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.node-pre-gyp.DELETE'
+ @angular/cli@1.1.1
added 823 packages and updated 1 package in 167.125s
[On.Store.UI] install -g @angular/cli successfully completed
> .npm [On.Store.UI] install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
> fsevents@1.1.1 install C:\Users\child\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents
> node install
+ @angular/cli@1.1.1
added 120 packages, removed 1 package and updated 1 package in 83.667s
[On.Store.UI] install -g @angular/cli successfully completed
>
```

My package json is :

```
    {
  "name": "@angular/cli",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "CLI tool for Angular",
  "main": "packages/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js",
  "trackingCode": "UA-8594346-19",
  "bin": {
    "ng": "./bin/ng"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node scripts/run-tool.js publish build",
    "test": "npm-run-all -c test:packages test:cli test:deps test:licenses test:messages",
    "e2e": "npm run test:e2e",
    "e2e:nightly": "node tests/run_e2e.js --nightly",
    "test:e2e": "node tests/run_e2e.js",
    "test:cli": "node tests/runner",
    "test:deps": "node scripts/publish/validate_dependencies.js",
    "test:inspect": "node --inspect --debug-brk tests/runner",
    "test:licenses": "node scripts/test-licenses.js",
    "test:messages": "node scripts/test-commit-messages.js",
    "test:packages": "node scripts/run-packages-spec.js",
    "eslint": "eslint .",
    "tslint": "tslint \"**/*.ts\" -c tslint.json -e \"**/config/schema.d.ts\" -e \"**/tests/**\" -e \"**/blueprints/*/files/**/*.ts\" -e \"node_modules/**\" -e \"tmp/**\" -e \"dist/**\"",
    "lint": "npm-run-all -c eslint tslint",
    "tool": "node scripts/run-tool.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "author": "Angular Authors",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-cli",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "common-tags": "^1.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
    "debug": "^2.1.3",
    "denodeify": "^1.2.1",
    "diff": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-normalize-entity-name": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-string-utils": "^1.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.1.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "fs-extra": "~3.0.1",
    "get-caller-file": "^1.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.19.0",
    "inflection": "^1.7.0",
    "inquirer": "^3.0.0",
    "isbinaryfile": "^3.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "loader-utils": "^1.0.2",
    "license-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.3",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "magic-string": "^0.19.0",
    "memory-fs": "^0.4.1",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.3",
    "node-modules-path": "^1.0.0",
    "nopt": "^4.0.1",
    "opn": "4.0.2",
    "portfinder": "~1.0.12",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-url": "^5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve": "^1.1.7",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.3",
    "rsvp": "^3.0.17",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "silent-error": "^1.0.0",
    "source-map": "^0.5.6",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "temp": "0.8.3",
    "typescript": "~2.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "walk-sync": "^0.3.1",
    "webpack": "~2.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.32",
    "@types/chalk": "^0.4.28",
    "@types/common-tags": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/denodeify": "^1.2.29",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.32",
    "@types/fs-extra": "~3.0.2",
    "@types/glob": "^5.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "@types/minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/mock-fs": "^3.6.30",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.36",
    "@types/request": "0.0.39",
    "@types/rimraf": "0.0.28",
    "@types/semver": "^5.3.30",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.15",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "conventional-changelog": "^1.1.0",
    "dtsgenerator": "^0.9.1",
    "eslint": "^3.11.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mock-fs": "^4.0.0",
    "npm-run": "^4.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.0",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "request": "^2.74.0",
    "resolve-bin": "^0.4.0",
    "rewire": "^2.5.1",
    "spdx-satisfies": "^0.1.3",
    "through": "^2.3.6",
    "tree-kill": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

=======tsConfig.js

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {    
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

my visual code compiler errors are mentioned below :

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. On.Store.UI (tsconfig project)  L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\node_modules\@angular\common\src\location\platform_location.d.ts  51  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. On.Store.UI (tsconfig project)  L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\node_modules\@angular\common\src\location\platform_location.d.ts  51  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. On.Store.UI (tsconfig project)  L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\node_modules\@angular\common\src\pipes\async_pipe.d.ts    45  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. On.Store.UI (tsconfig project)  L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\node_modules\@angular\compiler\src\aot\compiler_host.d.ts 25  Active
Error   TS2339  Property 'find' does not exist on type 'BillingPackage[]'.  On.Store.UI (tsconfig project)  L:\ESaleStore\On.Store.UI\src\On.Store.UI\wwwroot\app\Billing\Billing.Service.ts    27  Active
```

Comment: I dont see any exceptions on install, it actually says complete successfully

Comment: When i am compiling my source code, visual studio is showing many errors

Comment: edit your question, dont add that to the comments

Comment: did you created a new project using ng new [project]? the package.json in the question is the one from the @angular/cli

Comment: Jota , i had already mentioned these errors in my post above. you again asked for it that's' why i added here. This is the first command and gave the error then if i run all the other commands then it thorw more errors